Understanding the term $D^\alpha g$ in $|D^\alpha (fg) - fD^\alpha g|_{L^2} \leq C(|f|_{H^s} |g|_{L^\infty} + |\nabla f|_{L^\infty}|g|_{H^{s-1}})$
In the Paper "Remarks on the breakdown of smooth solutions for the 3-D Euler equations" (1984) by Beale, Kato, and Majda ((https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf01212349) we are using this inequality, where $f \in H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^3) \cap C^1$ and $g  \in H^{s-1} \cap C$. Here $s \geq 3$ and $|\alpha| \leq s$, with $\alpha$ being a multiindice.
Now you can proof this inequality relatively easily, if one assume $f,g \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. This just follows from the product rule, Hölder‘s inequality and the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality.Majda says now „this can be easily extended to the case $g \in H^{s-1}$ with going to a limit“. Of course $C_{c}^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^3)$ is dense in $ H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. So this should be the way to go.
My Experiences with density arguments is we start with one expression. Then adding a zero to estimate with density a using triangle inequality to apply, what we already knew about smooth functions. Estimating again with density and we see that all unwanted terms go to zero. Like in the following example for one of sobolevs inequality.
\begin{align*}
       \|Eu\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)} &\leq \|Eu - Eu_{m} \|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)} + \|Eu_{m}\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \\
       &\leq \epsilon + C \|u_{m}\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} \\
       &\leq \epsilon + C (\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} + \|u_{m} - u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}) \\
       &\leq  \epsilon + C (\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} + \epsilon)
   \end{align*}
Here $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, $Eu$ is the extension of u to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $(u_{m})_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \subset C_{c}^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ with $u_m \rightarrow u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$
Now my my Problems really start with the expression $D^\alpha g$, if $|\alpha| = s$, since now it is just not defined. I realise, that it cancels if one uses the product rule, but if we can do this, there would be no reason to argue with density. So Majda says, that this inequality is still true even so some terms on the left side may not exist.
I think i just do not understand how something can hold even though it doesn’t exist.
Thank you in advance.

Expressions of this type are often called commutator estimates.
Suppose $\{g_k\}_k \subseteq C^\infty_c$ such that $g_k \to g$ in $H^{s-1}$. Let us suppose we are in one dimension to avoid some details about which partial derivatives we are taking
$$ \begin{align}
D^s (fg_k) &= \sum_{\ell \leq s} \binom{s}{\ell} D^{s-\ell} f D^\ell g_k \\
&= f D^s g_k + \sum_{\ell \leq s-1} \binom{s}{\ell} D^{s-\ell} f D^\ell g_k \end{align}$$
$$ |D^s (fg_k) - fD^s g_k|_{L^2} = \left| \sum_{\ell \leq s-1} \binom{s}{\ell} D^{s-\ell} f D^\ell g_k \right|_{L^2}$$
We can now bound the RHS of this equation with an expression that does not contain $|g_k|_{H^s}$, e.g.
$$ |D^s (fg_k) - fD^s g_k|_{L^2} = \left| \sum_{\ell \leq s-1} \binom{s}{\ell} D^{s-\ell} f D^\ell g_k \right|\leq C(|f|_{H^s} |g_k|_{L^\infty} + |\nabla f|_{L^\infty}|g_k|_{H^{s-1}})$$
We can now pass to the limit $g_k \to g$
This is possible because the expression on the LHS does not actually contain the apparently singular term $|f D^s g_k|_{L^2}$, you can compare it to an expression like
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{x+1}{x} - \frac{1}{x}\right) = 1,$$
where we are cancelling out the term that blows up. I'm not sure if this answer really cuts to the heart of your question but I hope it will be of some use.
